# Where is hcidump on an android phone?

Tags: android, bluetooth

I am trying to troubleshoot a bluetooth connection and I cannot find hcidump on the Droid X2, Atrix or Galaxy.

According to this: https://sites.google.com/a/android.com/opensource/projects/bluetooth-faq I should have the BlueZ tools somewhere... question is where?!

I found and copied over binaries for l2ping, hciconfig, and hcitool from here: http://gitorious.org/android-obex/pages/Home

Where can I find the hcitool binary if it is not provided in the stock OS?

BTW, all three phones are rooted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a binary thanks to [this](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?p=17919969&posted=1#post17919969) post. A direct link to the hcidump download is [here](http://www.mediafire.com/?bslhsmbftyr48bb). This binary works on the Droid X2.

Comment: hcidump file links are dead :(

Comment: if you're brave enough, you could build it from this guys source: [link.](https://github.com/d34th4ck3r/Hcidump-in-Android) I've never heard of him, so I'm probably just going to slide on by...

Comment: Just to no wast time, the @Kraiden link don't works since the whole android bluetooth stack was changed, [Here](https://github.com/AlanZheng/hcidump-android) is another link that may help.